# ORA-02065: illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM with _allow_insert_with_update_check

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, oracle11gr2

I am trying to alter but it is giving below error- (database version -12.2.0.4)

SQL> alter system set "_allow_insert_with_update_check"=true scope=both;

alter system set "_allow_insert_with_update_check"=true scope=both
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02065: illegal option for ALTER SYSTEM

Comment: I believe that option is only valid for Oracle 12cR2 (12.2.x) and higher. If this is in support of an OEM upgrade, I believe you'd need to be using a more recent version of Oracle for the repository anyway.

Comment: Since this is a hidden, undocumented parameter, I'd suggest you open an SR with oracle support.  I started to say that you shouldn't even be attempting to set it without oracle support responding to a specific problem, but then I saw that it is specified in a published upgrade guide .. https://docs.oracle.com/en/enterprise-manager/cloud-control/enterprise-manager-cloud-control/13.3.1/emupg/index.html

Comment: @pmdba database version is - 12.2.0.4

Comment: please tag your question appropriately, then. you tagged almost every old, outdated version of Oracle and didn't include the version you're actually using (12cR2).

Comment: Below is the database version -

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

and I am following below oracle note for the error I am getting while running the RCU -

RCU Fails with ORA-28104, ORA-06512 Errors when 12.2.x Database is Used (Doc ID 2325686.1)



and non of the suggested statement here worked.

Answer (score 0):

Remove parenthesis
alter system set _allow_insert_with_update_check=true scope=both

Answer (score 0):

scope = spfile   and then bounce the database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

use this command

```
alter system set "_allow_insert_with_update_check" = true;
```